# gwt Button Error

Tags: gwt, gxt

Unable to remove this error, nothing is working although the same code is working fine on other systems.

"com.pariter.client.Button can not be found in source packages. Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly."

---

Adding Button Class from Comment.

```
package com.pariter.client;    

class Button extends com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button {

            public Button(String s) {
                super(s);
                this.setPixelSize(100, 25);
                this.addStyleName("button");
            }
        }
```

---

Adding Entry Point and Source Path Sections for `.gwt.xml` from comment

```
...
    <!-- Specify the app entry point class. --> 
    <entry-point class='com.pariter.client.LoginPage'/>

    <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code --> 
    <source path='client'/>
    <source path='shared'/>
</module>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I recall correctly, this error would occur if the `com.pariter.client.Button` is not in a package (or subpackage) defined in your `.gwt.xml`.

Check your `.gwt.xml`. i.e.

```
...
    <entry-point class='com.pariter.AppEntryPoint'/>

    <source path="client"/>
...

</module>
```

---

[Update]

You will either need to move your `com.pariter.client.LoginPage` Entry Point to `com.pariter.LoginPage` (and therefore update your `.gwt.xml`) or move your Button class to the package `com.pariter.client.client`

Comment: .gwt.xml contains both entry-point and source path still getting this error

Comment: @rahul.jain It has to do with the GWT Module (either yours or an inherited one) i.e. _Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly._ Does the button class belong to one of your GWT Modules?

Comment: yes button class belong to  one of my modules....

class Button extends  com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button{
 public Button(String s){
  super(s);
  this.setPixelSize(100, 25);
  this.addStyleName("button");
 }
}

Comment: Can you Post the _entry-point_ and _source-path_ sections of your `.gwt.xml`?

Comment: <!-- Specify the app entry point class.  
                         -->
  <entry-point class='com.pariter.client.LoginPage'/>

  <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
  <source path='client'/>
  <source path='shared'/>

Comment: The problem is that the Button is in the same package as the Entry Point. The Config you posted is expecting the Button class to be in the package com.pariter.client.client

Comment: @rahul.jain I'm glad we could figure it out. Do you mind marking my answer as the correct one?